# PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest dont send cookie

Tags: powershell, http, post, cookies, get

Why this PowerShell code dont send cookie.

[image]

Example:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://example.com/" -Headers @{
"method"="GET"
  "authority"="example.com"
  "scheme"="https"
  "path"="/"
  "pragma"="no-cache"
  "cache-control"="no-cache"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Google Chrome`";v=`"89`", `"Chromium`";v=`"89`", `";Not A Brand`";v=`"99`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "upgrade-insecure-requests"="1"
  "user-agent"="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36"
  "accept"="text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9"
  "accept-encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "accept-language"="ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"
  "cookie"="test1=none; test2=none"
}
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

The code is invalid powershell. I guess it is a bug in Postman.

As per the Powershell documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7

> *-Headers*
>
> Specifies the headers of the web request. Enter a hash table or dictionary.
> To set UserAgent headers, use the *UserAgent* parameter. You can't use this parameter to specify *User-Agent* or cookie headers.

So you must use the whole websession logic. See the `-SessionVariable` option to `Invoke-WebRequest`.